# Cumulative distribution function of hypergeometric distribution

Tags: pr.probability, co.combinatorics

Does anyone know a closed form or a good approximation of the cumulative distribution function of hypergeometric distribution?

Comment: Is there a particular range of parameters or arguments that you're interested in?  Different results apply in different ranges.

Comment: @John Let A is an event that follow hyper-geometric distribution, I want to calculate P(|A-E(A)|>d) for some d. If I use the notion in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution
Another parameters is that N is very large, and d<<N.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at:

An accurate computation of the hypergeometric distribution function

By Trong Wu  (ACM TOMS, 1993).